# How to passing value to new template by click on href function?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

i want to click on href and do javascript function to post some value to python and render new template with that data, this is my code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <a href="#" onclick="myFunction();">Click</a>

<script>
var jsvariable = 'hello world'
    function myFunction(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/getvalue",
            type: "post", //send it through get method
            data:{'jsvalue': jsvariable},

    })
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/getvalue', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getvalue():
    data = request.form['jsvalue']
    print(data)
    return render_template('index2.html', data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now the data that pass from ajax function to getvalue() in python that work properly but it not render to new template, so how can i fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Mate you don't even need ajax for this(I even think it's what's making a problem for you, correct me if I'm wrong but ajax makes a background POST request, it's like the template gets rendered to the background, you need a foreground request)

Also bad practice, you put your script before the body, it shouldn't even go in the head but as further down as possible

[Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

## server.py

```
@app.route('/getvalue', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getvalue():
    if request.method=='POST':
        data = request.form['jsvalue']
        return render_template("index2.html", data=data)
```

## index.html

```
<form action = "/getvalue" method = "POST">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "jsvalue"/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>
<script>
    var jsvariable = 'hello world';
    var el=document.getElementsByName("jsvalue");
    el[0].value=jsvariable;
</script>
```

## index2.html

```
{{data}}
```